# Scala: def vs val in Play2

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have been following the instruction in the Play! Framework Essentials book, and sometimes I see an action in controllers defined with a ***def***, and sometimes with a ***val***.

I know that def will reevaluate the expression when called, and val will immediately evaluate the expression, but in the context of a controller action, is there any difference?

Here is the sample code:

```
object Items extends Controller {

  val list = Action { implicit request =>
    ...
  }

  val create = Action { implicit request =>
    ...
  }

  def details(id: Long) = Action { implicit request =>
    ...
  }

  def update(id: Long) = Action { implicit request =>
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `def` will reevaluate the expression every time it is called, while `val` will be evaluated when the `Items` object is instantiated.

The implications of this is that the controller actions defined  in terms of a `def` will be **slower** as every time it is called, the controller needs to instantiate an `Action`, pass it the anonymous function that you have defined,...etc.

If the expression does not require any abstraction, it will always be more performant to use `val` as opposed to `def`.

Comment: I can replace all val with def, or all def with val and they all work with no problem.